# Run Kafka and Kafka-connect on different servers?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to know if Kafka and Kafka-connect can run on different servers? So a connector would be started on server A and send data from a kafka topic on server B to HDFS or S3 etc. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and for Production deployments this is typically recommended for resource reasons. Generally you'd deploy a cluster of Kafka Brokers (3+ for HA), and then a cluster of Kafka Cluster workers (as many as needed for throughput capacity / resilience) -- all on separate nodes.

For more details, see the [Confluent Enterprise Reference Architecture](https://www.confluent.io/whitepaper/confluent-enterprise-reference-architecture/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it.

I have my set of kafka servers and kafka connect applications are running in different machines and writing data in hdfs. you have to mention list of brokers in **bootstrap.servers** under worker properties file (config/connect-distributed.properties or config/connect-standalone.properties) instead of **localhost:9092**